# Read pictures from webcam in Java on Ubuntu?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

There are many questions on SO on how to read images from webcams in Java, but judging by the answers there does not seem to be a library which is actively developed and maintained.

My question is if it would make any difference if I limited the OS to Linux only? I know there's a device representing video, `/dev/video0`, can that be used for reading image data from a webcam using `java.io` somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
If you want to do something with the image, get opencv and its bindings, http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/

The page also has a link for Java example programs.

OLD_ANSWER:

You can use vlc, it has webcam support.

As far a Java is concerned, take a look the VLCJ project for the bindings.
http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/

For the OS bit of your question, on Linux webcam is implemented via v4l (video for linux) , but as far as I think, it won't be an issue for having it cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a command (external program, started from your Java code) which is handling the video reading of the webcam. But what do you want to do with the video stream?

Comment: Yes, I guess I could, but I would rather have it in "pure code". Currently I only need to grab a frame every once in a while, but later on I might need to grab frames faster.